# How to select the largest subset of pairs with unique elements?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have table of number pairs:

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 1
2 | 2
4 | 2
5 | 5
1 | 3
```

For each `b` I want to pick an `a` such as there are no 2 identical `a`s for different `b`s.

If I do a simple query with `group by`:

```
select * from t group by b
```

I get the following results back:

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 1
2 | 2
5 | 5
1 | 3
```

`a == 1` for `b == 1` and `b == 3`

What I want instead is something like this:

```
a | b
--+--
3 | 1
2 | 2
5 | 5
1 | 3
```

Could you help me with this problem? I assume that there's a known terminology for this kind of subset querying, but I'm not aware of it, and that makes searching for answers harder.

Bonus points if the query picks largest `a` for given `b` while keeping the given uniqueness constraint. For my example the result would be:

```
a | b
--+--
3 | 1
4 | 2
5 | 5
1 | 3
```

Comment: That sounds like a hard problem.  How would you resolve the case where two `b`'s only work out with a single `a`?  Anyway, I don't think this type of problem is meant to be solved in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first approach will be:

```
select MAX(a) as a,
       b
from t as t1
where NOT EXISTS(select a from t where b<>t1.b and a=t1.a)
      or 
      NOT EXISTS(select a from t where a in (select a from t where b=t1.b)
                 GROUP BY a 
                 HAVING COUNT(*)=1)

GROUP BY b
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27ab6b/9)</kbd>

We should group by `b` and find `MAX(a)` but from the special subrange of the main table. 
First we should get all `a` which aren't exist for another `b` (it is the first condition). 
But in the case of `b=3` we get the case that ALL `a` exist for other `b` so the second condition handles this case.

Comment: Seems accurate although it's very slow on a larger dataset. I have about 200k records of this kind. I've added indices for `a` and `b`. Is there any other way I could potentially speed up this operation?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select max(a),b from t group by b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 SELECT MAX(`a`) as `a`, `b` FROM Table1 GROUP BY `b`
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4897/8

Answer (score -2):

Please check this, I have not verified:-

```
SELECT max(a) AS a, b FROM t WHERE  GROUP BY b
```

Comment: Just `HAVING MAX(a)` without any operator ? This is incorrect.